# what is equal to DateTimeOffset.Now from C# in php

Tags: php

hello how is there something like DateTimeOffset.Now in php in C# it should return something like 1660991390 is there a way to do the same in php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.gmmktime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo time();
```

gives you the current unix timestamp.

```
1660991549
```